# UK visa refusal twice visit

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Can I apply for a UK standard visit visa (family visitor) after a 2-year interval of a UK visa refusal to attend British Army Assessment?

Comment: Why was the previous visa refused?

Comment: You can apply. Whether you will be successful depends on the reasons why your previous application was refused, and what younhave done to address those reasons.

Comment: @Kwame There is no restriction at all in the UK Immigration Rules to prevent anyone from re-applying for a visa after a refusal (or even after an entry ban). You can apply as many times as you like.

Comment: @Danil, they stated that i failed to explain how i calculated my claimed income from self-employment